# How to turn off Highlight File on Active Editor Change?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VS Code [October 2019 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_highlight-file-on-active-editor-change) includes a feature to automatically highlight the active file in the tree/list view.
How do I turn off this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting `SCM: Auto Reveal` seems to enable/disable that functionality for the source control tree, as in the image you linked to.  Uncheck it to disable.

Also `Explorer: Auto Reveal` for the explorer tree highlighting.